# How to ECHO command line output on Windows

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, command-line

Im trying to reproduce the following batch file but on command-line oneliner. Id like to be able to use this client in python scripts and to identify if a connection is made I need to be able to retrieve the error codes. I am calling the application via subprocess Any help would be appreciated

**BATCH FILE CODE**

```
ECHO OFF
START /WAIT rdp.exe /v:192.168.1.122 /u:xpuser /p:xpuser /batch 
ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

I have tried the below commands along with many variations but cant get what is expected. Information on the executable can be found [here](http://www.donkz.nl/)

**EXAMPLE**

```
c:\Python27>start /WAIT rdp.exe /v:192.168.1.122 /u:xpuser /p:xpuser /log /batch | ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%


c:\Python27>start rdp.exe /v:192.168.1.122 /u:xpuser /p:xpuser /batch || ECHO %ERRORLEVEL%
```

**SNIPPET OF PYTHON CODE**

```
   try:        
       cmdrdp = "rdp.exe /v:%s /u:%s /p:%s /log /batch" % (server, username, password)
       subprocess.check_output(cmdrdp)
   except CalledProcessError as e:
       print(e.returncode)
   else:
       print "Connected to: %s %s %s" % (server, username, password)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass a single string to `subprocess.check_output`, it's interpeted as the literal file name, if you want it to work you need to pass the `shell=True` argument.

However, the recommended way of using the `subprocess` family of functions is with a list of strings as argument:

```
subprocess.check_output(["rdp.exe", "/v:" + server, "/u:" + username, "/p:" + password, "/log", "/batch"])
```